# Unity3d change preview icon for files with assets extensions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3d.

How to change preview icon for files that has .assets extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview.html

This plugin does it: http://u3d.as/content/wit-entertainment/asset-preview/2Lz